# GParted won't detect Raid-0 in Ubuntu Lucid Lynx

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gparted, raid-0

On Ubuntu 9.10 it detected my nvidia RAID-0 (I'm using a 780i motherboard from Nvidia).

The problem is that when I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 gparted no longer detects the RAID EVEN with an Ubuntu 10.04 live-cd or after it's installed.

Also, at first I had to jump through hoops to get Ubuntu 10.04 working. I had to use the 9.10 live-cd create & format an empty ext4 partition and once it was made only then did Ubuntu 10.04 let me install it on my raid 0 partition that I created with the 9.04 live-cd.

Anyway, now that Ubuntu 10.04 is installed I wish to make the partition larger. But gparted only detects my two hard drives as if they weren't in a raid array (weird since Ubuntu 10.04 is booting from the Raid-0!), it just lists the hard drives separately. Anyone have any tips on how I can get gparted to work?

Comment: Is it a fake raid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kpartx package is necessary for GParted to see the RAID volumes.
See comment #5 on http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9631739

kpartx may be installed either with Synaptic Package Manager (System->Administration->Synaptic Package Manager) or from a command line:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kpartx

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you find this?

Comment: Indeed as Nicolae Babanu mentions, the necessary package is kpartx as it allows to work with fake RAID as well.